# Label of Image Plot in R

Tags: r, plot, label

I am using `image.plot` in R. Here is my simple code:

```
x=1:30
y=1:30
z=matrix(rnorm(900),30,30)
library(fields)
image.plot(x,y,z,col=ifelse(z<0,"red","blue"))
```

That gives me the following plot. How can I change the label on the right hand size to have just two colored horizontal bars:

red bar with the  text label of "negative" and
blue bar with the  text label of "positive"

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that you have specified the `col` argument correctly, as your plot seems to identify greater / less than zero points differently than using the default colours. (`image.plot(x,y,z,col=ifelse(z<0,"red","blue")) ; image.plot(x,y,z)` .  This seems to get something close to what you want (i think) `image.plot(x,y,z, breaks=c(min(z), 0, max(z)), col=c("red","blue"))`

Comment: Thanks, you are right ... the correct would be: `x=1:4
y=1:5
z=matrix(c(rep(1,10),rep(-2,10)),4,5)
par(mar=c(4,4,4,6))
par(xpd=TRUE)
image(x,y,z, breaks=c(min(z), 0, max(z)), col=c("red","blue"))
legend(4.5,4.5, inset=c(-0.2,3), legend=c("Negative","Positive"), pch=15, col=c("red","blue"),bty="n")
`

Comment: youre welcome, looks good stat.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `image.plot` was created in `library(fields)` was to make it easy to add a legend. If you don't need the legend as it is, you might as well use `image` in base R. In the following code, I first adjust the margins with `mar`, then I allow to write outside the plot with `par(xpd=TRUE)`. This is done using `inset` in the `legend` call.

```
par(mar=c(4,4,4,6))
par(xpd=TRUE)
image(x,y,z,col=ifelse(z<0,"red","blue"))
legend("right", inset=c(-0.2,0), legend=c("Negative","Positive"), pch=15, col=c("red","blue"),bty="n")
```

[image]

Comment: Using the legend like this is a nice approach, however the the col argument of the image call is incorrect (i know its not what the Q is about, but might be worth updating??)